# How ambigity is solved in derived class here?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public: 
    virtual void function1(){
        cout<<"base function1"<<endl;
    }
    virtual void function2()=0;
};

class base2
{
public: 
    virtual void function2()=0;
};

class derived : public base, base2
{
public:

    void function2(){
    cout<<"derived function"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  derived d;
  d.function2();
  d.function1();
}
```

Two base classes here contains function2() as pure virtual function. And derived class inherits both base classes. function2() is implemented in derived. How compiler resolves ambiguity in such scenario. Inputs are welcome.

Comment: you call `derived::function2` and `base::function1`, there is no ambiguity

Comment: Not in main() i was worried. But while inheriting in derived class function2 is implemented but compiler does accepts implementation as both base class have same function name.

Comment: Every class has its own `virtual function table`. If a base class has a `pure virtual function` then the `derived class` needs to implement that `pure virtual function`. All the `virtual functions` (including `pure virtual function`) are listed in the table of `derived class` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ambiguity. If you call the `function2()` on `derived`, the compiler knows exactly, which function to call (the `derived` version of it). If you call it on `base` or `base2` typed pointer/ref, the compiler also knows, what to call (via the virtual function table for that particular base).

The ambiguity happens in this case:

```
class base
{
public: 
    void func(){
        cout<<"base func"<<endl;
    }
};

class base2
{
public: 
    void func(){
        cout<<"base2 func"<<endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base, public base2
{
public:
    void func2(){
        func(); // ??? which one to call ???
    }
};
```

---

Why it works in the original case is that the compiler uses the `derived::function2` to implement both `base` and `base2` versions. In case of implementing it via virtual method tables (only one of possible implementations), there are (AFAIK) normally two virtual tables for each base in derived, and both contain pointers to the same `function2`.

Comment: Thanks axalis. But in my code hw compiler takes care of accepting the implementation.

Comment: @DeekshithGowda Unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how the compiler is written?

Answer (score 1):

The output of your program is:

```
derived function
base function1
```

Also, there is no ambiguity in resolving the function call `function2()` because you have used the concrete derived class object `d`. `class derived` has member function `function2()` of its own. You just tried to call the member function of a class via object of that class.

I guess you were looking for [Diamond Problem in case of Multilevel Inheritance.](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem/)